# When is require ever preferred over require_once in PHP?

Tags: php, require, require-once

The way I see it, if a file has been included once then any object, function or member in it is defined.

require_once checks if the file is included and if so, doesn't include it again. But when would the event ever arise that someone would go 'this file has already been included so I can use the class inside it, but I'd better include it again because this script needs it'?

Am I missing something?

Comment: Just one example of the top of my head: you are using a template for list items and include/require that template for each item (in the HTML output).

Comment: Another easy example (although it illustrates a bad practice): the application does not use class autoloading, so each component has lots of `require_once` for its dependencies.

Comment: Naive answer: for when you want to inlcude a file multple times.

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question. Why would you want to include a file multiple times? I see a few answers about template engines but having never used one I don't really understand. If a function is defined, why does it need to be defined again?

Comment: While templating you wouldn't necessarily include a function. More likely you would include the HTML code (with PHP-bits for variable content) that renders the repeated content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `include_once` / `require_once` for classes files, and `include` / `require` for html code (let's say a form for example). You shouldn't redeclare the class, but you could insert html code multiple times in your code.

Comment: Ahh now I see. Coming from a statically typed, compiled language background it wasn't immediately obvious. I'm thinking of it in a very 'backend' way.

Answer (score 1):

In ye olde days before proper classes, I would sometimes use require inside a for or while loop when doing large imports. Along the same lines, template engines use it for repeated includes of the same file that should fail if the file is missing.